# a forgotten simple way to convert list of list to list of tuple: [[1,2], [3,4]] -> [(1,2), (3,4)]

Tags: python, list, tuples

Half a year ago, when I was using [`vedo`](https://vedo.embl.es/#refs) (a python module for visualization), I happened to learned that there is a simple way to convert list of list to list of tuple, for example

```
 [[1, 2], [3, 4]] -> [(1, 2), (3, 4)],
```

by using **`.r_[a, b]`**(or **`._r[a, b]`** ? ), where **`a`** and **`b`** are some axis parameters(?).

Unfortunately, however I tried to search it on the Internet today, I can't found any evidence of such a way (np.r_ can't do that).
So I want to know does it ever exist, if so can somebody teach me how to use it, thanks.

Comment: `.r_` is from `numpy`, and doesn't apply to lists or tuples.

Comment: That seems cryptic and not the primary use-case of whatever you are referring to,  why not just `list(map(tuple, mylist))` which everyone would understand? Or `[tuple(x) for x in mylist]`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, and I'm also using these methods that you mentioned. asking this question is merely out of interest.

Comment: Again, **almost certainly** there is no such method to convert a list of lists to a list of tuples... or you misunderstood its purpose

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This is hardcoded

```
def convert(listt):
    lists = []
    for sub_list in listt:
        if isinstance(sub_list, list):
            lists.append(tuple(sub_list))
        else:
            lists.append(sub_list)
    return lists
  
listt = [1,2,[1, 2, 3, 4], [1,2,3], "st"]
print(convert(listt))
```